# Use arrow keys instead of mouse in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is there a way to use arrow keys to look around and control direction (instead of the mouse).

The mouse in Skyrim is quite messed up.  I tweaked it to be more responsive (because the default settings are horrible).  But now the screen jitters as I move around (cause my mouse movements are not totally smooth.)

It would be really nice for normal walking around to use keys and just use the mouse in combat.

Is there a way to do this?  WASD for walking and Arrow Keys for looking?

Comment: There's no way to remap the mouse movement to keys, since it's a completely different control type (x/y-axis versus keypress). You might want to consider using a PC-compatible gamepad if the mouse control is that bad.

Comment: I use my 360 controller, and it works fantastically, with mods to enable more hotkeys of course.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. The movement of a mouse has several variables (speed, direction, etc) that cannot be directly simulated by the four arrow keys.

You may want to try updating to v1.2, which is supposed to fix some mouse issues. ([Source](http://www.bethblog.com/2011/11/30/skyrim-1-2-update/))

Also, try disabling mouse acceleration if you haven't already.

1. Open your SkyrimPrefs.ini file in My Documents\My Games\Skyrim
2. Modify bMouseAcceleration=1 to be bMouseAcceleration=0

Some people have also reported some mouse improvement from disabling VSync, though it's not generally recommended due to graphical glitches

1. Open your SkyrimPrefs.ini file in My Documents\My Games\Skyrim
2. Add iPresentInterval=0 to the bottom of the [Display] section

Answer (score 1):

I agree the use of cursors to turn is a gross omission in Skyrim, I played all FPP games in the past with cursors & used the mouse to aim or HUD actions, when using the mouse to turn you have to keep lifting the mouse off the mouse mat and then turning again, this causes a delay and is a lot less efficient than just tapping or holding the cursor key as anyone who plays FPP shooters knows, also if you have RSI which makes constant mouse use difficult this can ruin the game. I have noticed other Steam based FPP games dropping cursor support and it's an absolute nightmare.

As a solution, download autohotkey from autohotkey.com and use a script like the one below to use the left and right mouse cursors in Skyrim to turn left and right, however there are a few issues, e.g. for some reason the movement is reversed when in overview mode vs. driving mode, so if you use overview mode you might need to switch the left & right statements below. You might also want to change the speed settings shown as 99 below, 100 is the slowest 0 is fastest mouse movement. Notice also how I have had to save the vertical cords and then set the current Y position back to this to avoid sending the view to the top of the screen, this happened when using a more basic script such as `MouseMove, 1, 0, 0, R`.

If anyone can come up something better I'd be interested to see this.

P.s. you can also compile the script into an executable (exe) file which can make it easier to run at startup etc.

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.


CoordMode, Mouse, Screen

MouseGetPos, xpos, ypos


Left::
MouseMove, -1, -1+1, 99, R 
MouseGetPos, lxpos, lypos
MouseMove, lxpos, ypos
return

Right::
MouseMove, 1, -1+1, 99, R
MouseGetPos, rxpos, rypos
MouseMove, rxpos, ypos
return
```